# Groupby function on dataset python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have following dataset from which I am using for my research. Final output is slope.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df=pd.read_excel('I:/Python/Data/Copy.xlsx')


df_np=np.array(df)

x=np.array(df_np[:,14],dtype=float)
y=np.array(df_np[:,12],dtype=float)



for i, pair in enumerate(zip(x, y)):


slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(np.delete(x,i),np.delete(y,i))

print('slope', slope, 'for data without pair', i, ':', pair)
```

---

The help I need in the above code is that the Test Events are outputting separately and Slope values are outputted seperately. There is no 1:1 relation between test_events and slope values.

Say there are 10 IDs within every test event.

Test IDs=0,1,2,...9

Test event=11, 12, 13, 14

This means I need slopes for every ID in every test event

```
Test event     ID     x=axis      y-axis     slope
```

Any help on this will be great

Comment: I know pandas has a groupby() method. Give that a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to group your DataFrame by `Test Event`, then loop over the `groupby` object and run your existing code on each group. Read about iterating over groups [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df=pd.read_excel('I:/Python/Data/Copy.xlsx')

grouped = df.groupby('Test Event')

for test_event, g in grouped:
    print('Test Event: {}'.format(test_event))
    df_np=np.array(g)

    x=np.array(df_np[:,1],dtype=float)
    y=np.array(df_np[:,2],dtype=float)

    for i, pair in enumerate(zip(x, y)):

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(np.delete(x,i),np.delete(y,i))

    print('slope', slope, 'for data without pair', i, ':', pair)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The output should be as in table above with 20 different slope values(10 slope values per event type). I am getting test_events printed out first followed by the values for slope.

Comment: I mean test_events are printed out differently and slope values are printed out differently There is no slope values for every test event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any array as input to `linegress` function.. this includes series in you dataframe:

```
linregress(df['x-axis'], df['y-axis'])
```

You can `apply` to each group when using pandas groupby

```
grouped = df.groupby('Test Event')
grouped.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(linregress(x['x-axis'], x['y-axis']))).rename(columns={
    0: 'slope',
    1: 'intercept',
    2: 'rvalue',
    3: 'pvalue',
    4: 'stderr'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: @JLuxton, hanks for the reply. The output should be as in table above with 20 different slope values(10 slope values per event type). I am getting test_events printed out first followed by the values for slope

Comment: I mean test_events are printed out differently and slope values are printed out differently There is no slope values for every test event.

Comment: So you are wanting a running slope? It’s not clear to me what your desired output is.